# How to update location for every 5 seconds in firebase realtime database (js code)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**I want to update location in every 5 seconds in firebase realtime database.
There is some logic problem that I am not able to recognize**

**This code is updating the location 3 time a minute. But I want to update location in each 5 seconds**

*I have asked this question to,Google send me this mail:
I'm Adrian and I'll help you with this case.
Looking at the example code that you sent, I used  the snippet where you write to the Database and works fine. Regarding the times that the location is updated on the Database, it looks like an error in the script logic.*

**How to update location in 5 seconds ?**

**Here is my code**

```
// Start the session
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<body>
<body onload="getLocation()">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])&&isset($_POST['user'])) {
    $_SESSION['userGet']=$_POST['user'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['userGet'])) {
    echo $form_value = $_SESSION['userGet'];
}
?>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" id="idd" name="user" value="<?php echo $_POST['user'] ?>"  />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
var lati;
var longi;
var idd;

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        function showPosition(position) {
            n1= position.coords.latitude ;
            n2= position.coords.longitude;
            lati = n1;
            longi = n2;
            var id = document.getElementById("idd").value;
            idd = parseInt(id);
            firebase.database().ref('Location').child(idd).set({
                identity: idd,
                latitude: lati,
                longitude : longi
            });
        }
    }

    else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.reload();
    },5000);    
} 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the posted form and PHP have to do with the issue? Can you please explain how the posted code suppose to work? It's a bit unclear

Comment: In this line: `firebase.database().ref('Location').child(idd).set({`, `.child()` expects a string but is getting a number via `idd = parseInt(id);`.

Comment: I have edited code to strings but still it doesn't work.Instead it is not even updating the location per minute

Comment: Can you show the changes?

Comment: Can anyone write this code with correct logic. I'm not able to solve this problem. Please solve this problem

Comment: Rob Moll I have edited this code but still it is not updating.Here the code  var id = document.getElementById("idd").value;
   firebase.database().ref('Location').child(id).set({
    identity: id,
    latitude: lati,
    longitude : longi
   });